# How can I redirect to a page with 302 statuscode in controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am about to redirect to a page with a 302 status code.

```
public IActionResult test()
        {
            ///some logic
            return RedirectPermanent("www.google.com");
        }
```

However, after I used the `RedirectPermanent` method only receive a 301 status code.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the method `RedirectPermanent`this produces the corresponding statuscode 301 **Moved permanently**

When you want 302 (**Found**) then try using the `Redirect`-Method

You can look it up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.redirect?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Update:
Final Solution in Comments

> Another idea could be to create an 'ActionFilter' for this specific
> usecase. You can use the Redirect Method and in the OnActionExecuted
> Method of the ActionFilter you can change the status code manualy to
> 302

Comment: I have found this. However, it is so strange that there is no public abstract void Redirect (string location, bool permanent); in visual studio even I used the asp.net core 6.

Comment: What is the reason that you need 302 in this case? Because 301 expresses just exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: I wanna counter the web crawler. When there is a probable web crawler, it will redirect to a page with 302 status code to validate it by Google Recaptcha.

Comment: Another idea could be to create an 'ActionFilter' for this specific usecase. You can use the `Redirect` Method and in the `OnActionExecuted` Method of the ActionFilter you can change the status code manualy to 302

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this way.